# Custom confirmation component not opening inside v-menu in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to show confirmation component whenever any button clicked on header is clicked. It is opening whenever I click other element except from dropdown using v-menu.

App.vue

```
<template>
  {{isConfirmDialogVisible}}
  <div class="header">
    <div class="left-menus">
      <div
        v-for="(item, index) in items"
        :key="index"
        class="menu"
        style="background-color: red; gap: 10px; padding: 10px"
        @click="opendialog()"
      >
        {{ item.title }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <v-menu open-on-hover transition="slide-y-transition">
      <template #activator="{ props }">
        <div style="cursor: pointer">
          <v-icon v-bind="props">mdi-menu-down</v-icon>
        </div>
      </template>

      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, index) in userOptions"
          :key="index"
          class="dropdown"
          @click="opendialog()"
        >
          <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
    <Confirmation
      v-model="isConfirmDialogVisible"
      v-if="isConfirmDialogVisible"
      action-button="submit"
      action-button-left="cancle"
      action-button-right="confirm"
    >
      <div style="font-size: 20px">Are you sure？</div>
    </Confirmation>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import Confirmation from './Confirmation.vue'

  const isConfirmDialogVisible = ref(false)

  const userOptions = ref([{ title: 'Logout' }, { title: 'Setting' }])

  const opendialog = () => {
    isConfirmDialogVisible.value = true
  }

  export default {
    components: {
      Confirmation,
    },
    data: () => ({
      items: [
        { title: 'Click Me' },
        { title: 'Click Me' },
        { title: 'Click Me' },
        { title: 'Click Me 2' },
      ],

      opendialog,
      isConfirmDialogVisible,
      userOptions,
    }),
  }
</script>

<style>
  .header .left-menus {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 16px;
  }
</style>
```

Confirmation.vue

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialogVisible" persistent activator="parent" width="auto">
    <div class="dialog_container">
      <v-card>
        <div class="card-components">
          <div class="warning_image"></div>
          <v-card-text>
            <slot></slot>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn class="back" @click="closeDialog"
              >{{ actionButtonLeft }}</v-btn
            >
            <v-btn @click="confirmSelection" class="confirm-submit">
              {{ actionButtonRight}}
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </div>
      </v-card>
    </div>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
<script>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  export default {
    props: {
      modelValue: Boolean,
      actionButton: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      actionButtonRight: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      actionButtonLeft: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: 'cancel',
      },
    },

    emits: ['update:modelValue', 'confirmAction'],
    setup(props, { emit }) {
      const dialogVisible = ref(false)
      const closeDialog = () => {
        dialogVisible.value = false
        emit('update:modelValue', false)
      }
      const confirmSelection = () => {
        closeDialog()
        emit('confirmAction')
      }

      const returnBack = () => {
        closeDialog()
      }

      const handleOutsideClick = event => {
        console.log(event)
      }

      return {
        dialogVisible,
        closeDialog,
        returnBack,
        confirmSelection,
        handleOutsideClick,
      }
    },
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .card-components {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 24px;
  }

  .dialog_container {
    height: 225px;
    width: 648px;
  }
  .v-card {
    padding: 16px 24px 24px 24px;
  }
  .v-card-text {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .warning_image {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .v-card-actions {
    min-height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .v-card-actions .v-btn {
    border: 1px solid #9ca3af;
    color: #9ca3af;
    width: 140px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  .v-card-actions .confirm-submit {
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #41a1e0;
    background: #41a1e0;
  }
</style>
```

I am trying to show confirmation component whenever any button clicked on header is clicked. It is opening whenever I click other element except from dropdown using v-menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Confirmation.vue, the VDialog relies on the parent component to become visible:

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialogVisible" activator="parent">
  ...
</template>
<script setup>
  const dialogVisible = ref(false)
  ...
</script>
```

So when a Confirmation component becomes visible, VDialog will show the dialog and update `dialogVisible`.

For some reason, this does not work when VMenu is visible. Instead, use the component's `modelValue` to trigger the dialog, which is more meaningful anyway. There are several ways to do this, one is to set `dialogVisible` in a watcher:

```
setup(props, { emit }) {
  const dialogVisible = ref(false)
  watchEffect(() => dialogVisible.value = props.modelValue)
```

You then have to remove the `activator="parent"` for it to work.

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Now I have to click twice on left menus for model to open. Once it opens and close immediately , 2nd time is works properly.

Comment: Oh, yes, you have to remove the `activator="parent"` for it to work.